# Android: click on widget event

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I am completly new to android programming and I try to get clicking on an android widget working:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) 
{
// Loop through all widgets
for(int i=0;i < appWidgetIds.length;i++) {
    int appWigedid = appWidgetIds[i];
    // Create an intent to launce something
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,TestActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);


    // Get the layout for the app widget and attach on click listener
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.initial_layout);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.UselessMessage, pendingintent);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.UselessMessage,"This text is useless");
    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    manager.updateAppWidget(appWigedid,views);
}
}
```

my TestActivity class is just a stub because still trying to find out how it is called.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    System.out.println("On Start called!");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("on create called!");
};
```

}

The setting of the Text works. But the onStart method of the TestAcitivity is never executed (other sysout messages work). When I tap on the widget android logs:

```
12-25 17:17:43.054  1279  1392 I ActivityManager: Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.rfc1149.android.simple/.TestActivity bnds=[120,272][360,371] }
```

which would suggest that the activity is created but the onCreate does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `TestActivity` is defined in your manifest.

Comment: Yes thanks. I am feeling stupid that I missed that. Your book is great by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Your onCreate() method does work and will log to the LogCat which is viewable on the DDMS perspective (if your using Eclipse).For your onStart() method to work, you must call super.onStart() in your overriden onStart() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Log.d("myTAG", "debug text")` instead of  `System.out.println("debug text")`

Comment: I know but that is merely a nicer way of doing the output. It makes no difference.